# Debian 10 install --- Wifi works when booting from usb, but "no ethernet card" while installing

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, system-installation

I am switching the linux partition of my laptop (a Lenovo Flex 14) from Ubuntu to Debian 10. In keeping with my usual practice, I first booted from a live usb stick, to check that nothing would be too inconvenient upon installation. Using debian-live-10.3.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso downloaded [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.3.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/) booting from the usb stick worked like a charm --- wifi, trackpad, etc. were all in working order.

However, once I began installation (using the GUI installer), the installer detected no network hardware. The wifi card in question is the RealTek RTL8822be, however, manually selecting the `rtlwifi` driver had no effect. When I boot from usb, and run `lspci -k`, the relevant output is

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Kernel driver in use: r8822be
    Kernel modules: r8822be
```

I am at a loss for what to do (I am, unfortunately, quite inexpert in such matters). The laptop does not have an ethernet port, and I don't currently own a dongle for that purpose. Ideally, I could get the wifi working during installation, but I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for how to get a functional installation of Debian on my machine.

Comment: That Wifi adapter probably needs special firmware in order to run. I think there is Debian installation media that **does** include the non-free firmware, you'll need to search around the Debian installation media. Alternatively I think the installer allows you to add the non-free firmware from an aditional medium. You'll have to search through the installation manual.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The debian installation I'm using (see link above) is the one containing non-free firmware. Part of what confuses me is that the version I am using allows me to use wifi when booting from a usb drive, while the official version does not.

Comment: You need package firmware-realtek to supplement the rtlwifi driver.

Comment: Is the package contained in the non-free iso then, since the wifi works when booting from the usb drive? Regardless, I'll put the firmware-realtek package on a second storage device, and see if that helps.